# FZAcordion TableView Text goes Beyond the bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to IOS and anyhow i have implemented the FZAccordion from [HERE](https://github.com/fuzz-productions/FZAccordionTableView). Now my problem is when i have a long text in header section and cells it goes beyond the bounds.So how can i get rid of this problem so that no matter how long is the text it always fits in the screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,estimatedHeightForRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension}
```

This will automatically resizes your text in your cells.